# Is the composite function integrable？

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be a Riemann integrable function defined on$[a,b]$ and let $g$ be a differentiable function with continuous on $[c,d]$.If the range of $g$ is contained in $[a,b]$,Is $f \circ g$ Riemann integrable on$[c,d]$？

If $g^{'}$ is non-zero on$[c,d]$,then the answer is positive.Go a step further ,let us remove this condition (as mentioned above),whether it will get the same conclusion？

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\colon [-1,1]\to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=-1$ if $x\le0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x> 0$.

Now let $g\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb R_+ \cup \{0\}$ be a [smooth function which vanishes on a cantor set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set) $C$ with positive measure.

Since Cantor sets are nowhere dense $f\circ g$ can not be continuous on $C$, but [Riemann integrable functions have to be continuous almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).

Comment: Of cause I want the maximum of $g$ is not bigger than $1$.